# Space combined with input works, but stops by itself

Tags: autohotkey

I'm playing a game and I want to press space to jump, however when I hold space and scroll down on my mousewheel I want it spammed for bunny hopping purposes.

Space & Wheeldown::Send {Space} is what im using but when this is used the spamming space works. however I cant press space to jump by itself anymore. also while spamming it. it seems to drop inputs with my free scroll and isnt pressing space on every frame. i need this done for some tricks but maybe need its inputs slowed for this specific one? idk. im terrible and new to AHK so maybe its simple but i just want some code i can copy paste please to get it all working.  my current entire script looks like this.

```
#NoEnv
#MaxHotkeysPerInterval 99000000
#HotkeyInterval 99000000
#KeyHistory 0
ListLines Off
Process, Priority, , H
SetBatchLines, 0
SetKeyDelay, 0, 0
SetMouseDelay, 0
SetDefaultMouseSpeed, 0
SetWinDelay, 1



#IfWinActive LavenderIsland
    r::escape
    $l::
      While GetKeyState("l","P")
      Send, {RButton}
    Return

c & Wheeldown::Send {Rshift}
c & Wheelup::Send {Rshift}
f & Wheelup::Send {right}
Space & Wheeldown::Send {Space}
```